# Reflection across the line y = x in 3 Dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question asks, "What is the matrix for the reflection across the line y = x in 3 Dimensions?"

I know the matrix for the reflection across the line y = x in 2 Dimensions is:
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I am not sure how to find the matrix for the reflection in 3 Dimensions. Is this correct?

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to ask for reflection about a line in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @ElliotG Sure it does. Reverse the orthogonal rejection from the line, just as you would for a reflection in a plane. It’s effectively a rotation through an angle of $\pi$, of course.

Comment: That said, in $\mathbb R^3$, $y=x$ is the equation of a *plane*, not a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & -1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

We need to send $z$ to $-z$.